# Request header field Range is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: apache, header

I'm trying to get my video with a HLS JS and I'm getting the follow error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/video.ts. Request header field Range is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

I'm using the Apache configuration:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Key, Content-Length, Authorization"


    AddType video/webm            .webm
    AddType video/mp4             .mp4
    AddType video/ogg             .ogv
    AddType application/x-mpegurl .m3u8

    # hls transport stream segments:
    AddType video/mp2t            .ts
    # subtitle text tracks:
    AddType text/vtt              .vtt
```

I googled a little and i would like to know what headers I should remove/add?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just added

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Range"
```