# Access resources of secondary server running different port apache2

Tags: php, html, configuration, apache2

I'm currently running a main server from a raspberry pi (32 GB) and a secondary server (4 TB) running as the file storage server. Both servers are running Debian Linux with Apache2 installed. I've been successful to bring PHP output from secondary server to main server with this code:

Main server:

```
<?php
    $results = file_get_contents('http://example.org:700/handle.php');
    echo $results;
?>
```

Secondary Server

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.org');

    //Rest of code
?>
```

So I came to the problem where the main server would be able to show pictures and play mp3/wav from the secondary server, but in my case, it wouldn't work with FLAC (with a bit of javascript code), it simply showed me this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.org:700/music/soundfile.flac. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.org' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I know there is nothing wrong with the javascript coding because it will play music from other websites like this example: [Debussy_-_Pour_les_accords.flac](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5e/Debussy_-_Pour_les_accords.flac) and has worked just fine earlier.

I simply want to allow all traffic between the two servers to be secure and with no Access-Allow-Origin errors. Is it something in the apache2.conf or other configuration files that can help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35707821/6802309

as simple as it looks.
this is how to fix this:

1. sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
2. Put in this code at the bottom:

.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "http://example.org"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
    Header set Access-Control-Expose-Headers: "Content-Length"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, HEAD"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Range"
</IfModule>
```

3. Enable headers in config file: sudo a2enmod headers
4. Check for errors do: sudo apachectl -k graceful
5. sudo service apache2 reload
6. sudo service apache2 restart

Done